# Making a String with literal r and variables Python

Tags: python, string-literals

I'm currently trying to make abstract methods for something like this:

```
preset_create("TaggingAgain", r'{"weight": 0, "precondition": "{\"_tags\":\"tagged\"}"}')
```

In my abstraction the User is able to make Precondition objects within a Preset object which then gets created.

It's currently something like this:

```
data = str({"weight" : preset.weight, "precondition" : "{}"})
data = data.replace("\'", "\"")
data = data.replace("}\"", "\"%(n)s\":\"%(v)s\"}" % {"n" : precondition.name,"v" : precondition.value})
```

(shortened Version because I'll add being able to add multiple preconditions with a "for in" later)

My problem is that the {\"_tags\":\"tagged\"} part needs to be in r'' to work and I don't know how to do that when there are variables in it.

Other code that might help understanding:

```
class Precondition(object):

    def __init__(self, name, operator, value):
        self.name = name
        self.value = value


class Preset(object):

    def __init__(self, name, weight, *preconditions):
        self.name = name
        self.weight = weight
        self.preconditions = preconditions


precondition = Precondition("_tag", "", "tagged")
createdPreset = Preset("TaggingAgain", "0", precondition)
preset_create(createdPreset)
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anybody else needs this in the future, heres how I've done it (using json which gre_gor posted a link to in a comment to my question).

Starting with the string:

```
precon = ("{\"%(n)s\":\"%(v)s\"}" % {"n" : precondition.name,"v" : precondition.value})
```

Another way to get this would be to add this to Precondition:

```
def as_dict(self):
    return {self.name: self.value}
```

And then use it like this:

```
precons = str(precondition.as_dict())
precons = precons.replace("\'", "\"")
```

Both of these ways should leave you with a string like this:

```
{"_tag":"tagged"}
```

Then use json.dumps to do the same that r'' would do

```
precon = json.dumps(precon)
```

After that it should look like this:

```
"{\"_tag\":\"tagged\"}"
```

Since json.dumps adds " at the start and at the end, remember to get rid of them if you don't need them.

Comment: Why don't you simply add the following method to the `Precondition` class

`def as_dict(self):
     return { self.name: self.value }
`

and then `precon = precondition.as_dict()`